# Bug? Rosbag filter and /tf_static

Tags: ros, rosbag, tf-static, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all

I am using a .bag file with RTAB-map ROS. It uses some static transforms between different camera frames to do the mapping.

**Edit: An example bag file that shows the buggy behavior can be downloaded here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6ox0xq6ctg2b9jl/small_test.bag.tar.gz?dl=0**

The launch file to launch RTAB-Map can be found here: https://pastebin.com/ZhXb5r5U

When I feed "data.bag" into RTAB-map, it works fine.
Now, I create a dummy filtered rosbag, using:

```
rosbag filter data.bag data_filtered.bag "topic != '/thistopicdoesntexist'"
```

As this topic doesn't exist, it should create an identical .bag file. However, when I try to feed "data_filtered.bag" into RTAB-map, I get many errors like:

```
[ WARN] [1494031985.023853640, 1493939596.985478852]: Could not get transform from camera_depth to camera_color after 0.100000 seconds (for stamp=1493939594.615704)! Error=". canTransform returned after 0.10093 timeout was 0.1.".
```

1. It seems that the filtered bag somehow is missing data from the static TF transforms. When I "rostopic echo -b data_filtered.bag", however, it shows that the static transforms are there.
2. It seems that the dummy filtering actually alters the .bag. Both MD5 hash and file size are changed between "data.bag" and "data_filtered.bag"! No compression is used. Why is that?

Maybe the problem is related to the time stamp? In any case, I am using use_sim_time=true, and I am also using --clock when playing back the .bag files.

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

- ibd

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261187/bug?-rosbag-filter-and-/tf_static/) by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-05-05

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-05-08**:
Do you have a small rosbag to share?

**Comment by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on 2017-05-08**:
Updated the original post with a bag file and the launch file I use to launch RTAB-map.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-05-08**:
This looks similar to https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/685

**Comment by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on 2017-05-08**:
ahendrix, it seems related indeed. Is there a clean fix for the .bag files I already have? Maybe changing the timestamp of the tf_static topic messages? Another idea I have is to setup a bunch of static_transform publishers. But, it would be a bit tedious for my workflow...

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2017-05-09**:
I tested the small bag and I can reproduce the problem in RVIZ too: when selecting Fixed Frame option, the static transforms won't show up in the pop-up menu with the "filtered" bag. Like ahendrix pointed out, it is like the static transforms are not latched anymore after filtering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Static transforms are not latched anymore after filtering, see issue referred by@ahendrix in comments above: https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/issues/685

Workaround: create again the static transforms (from `$ rostopic echo /tf_static` of the original bag):

```
<launch>
   <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link1_broadcaster" args="0 0 0 0.0797399667325 0.0797399667325 -0.702596283584 0.702596283584 device imu 100" />
   <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link2_broadcaster" args="0.0614856 0.00362063075446 -0.00414834496616 -0.990888233858 -0.00632257304794 0.00756104017168 0.134325588569 device camera_depth 100" />
   <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link3_broadcaster" args="0.0107366 0.00259880751323 -0.00281526009239 -0.990532183761 -0.00782511402323 0.00422548927873 0.136992356591 device camera_fisheye 100" />
   <node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="link4_broadcaster" args="0.0614856 0.00362063075446 -0.00414834496616 -0.990888233858 -0.00632257304794 0.00756104017168 0.134325588569 device camera_color 100" />
</launch>
```

Also don't forget to use `<param name="use_sim_time" value="true"/>` with `rosbag play --clock` when replaying the bags.

I also noticed that the clock published by the bag is not synchronized with stamps in topics: it starts at time ~1494273103.819191 while topics start at time ~1494273096.775229216. Topics are ~7 seconds in the past. Is the clock of the computer recording the bag synchronized with tango clock?

cheers,

Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2017-05-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on 2017-05-09**:
Thank you for the workaround. At least these transforms are constant across all rosbags.
I try to synchronize the time between the Tango device and the computer by connecting both to the internet and updating from a time server. However, I find that the tango clock will drift substantially.

**Comment by [ibd](https://answers.ros.org/users/29147/ibd/) on 2017-05-09**:
I just did some tests, and it seems that the tango tablet clock will drift as much as 1 second in 30 minutes when not connected to the internet!